# How to access single value from this type of List?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I have a List Like this:**

```
final List _subcoll=[
    {'name':'Java','pdfurl':'pdf1','thumbnail':'1'},
    {'name':'Dart','pdfurl':'pd2','thumbnail':'2'},
    {'name':'JavaScript','pdfurl':'pdf3','thumbnail':'3'},
    {'name':'PHP','pdfurl':'pdf4','thumbnail':'4'},
    {'name':'Python','pdfurl':'pdf5','thumbnail':'5'},
  ];
```

**How Can I Access a Single value such as name= java, and pdffile=pdf1?`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know whether you have found an answer to that, but here is the solution **[more basic precisely]** which you want to do in order to get the desired result.

Basically, it is just looping through the array, and then fetching the data like this: `array[index][dictionary_key_name]`

*Dictionary_key is nothing but {} data*

```
// In this case we have keys like 'name', 'pdfurl' and value like 'Java', and 'thumbnail'
// Every key is connected to the value in dictionary or hashmap/hashmap
dictionary = {key: value}
```

```
void main(){
  final List _subcoll=[
    {'name':'Java','pdfurl':'pdf1','thumbnail':'1'},
    {'name':'Dart','pdfurl':'pd2','thumbnail':'2'},
    {'name':'JavaScript','pdfurl':'pdf3','thumbnail':'3'},
    {'name':'PHP','pdfurl':'pdf4','thumbnail':'4'},
    {'name':'Python','pdfurl':'pdf5','thumbnail':'5'},
  ];

  /* 
     You can do whatever in the output you want
     My output is to just show you how it is working

    Just focus on how I got the result, _subscoll[index][hashkey]
  */
  for(int i=0; i<_subcoll.length; i++){
    print('name => ${_subcoll[i]['name']}, pdfurl => ${_subcoll[i]['pdfurl']}');
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
name => Java, pdfurl => pdf1
name => Dart, pdfurl => pd2
name => JavaScript, pdfurl => pdf3
name => PHP, pdfurl => pdf4
name => Python, pdfurl => pdf5
```

Play around with that more, and let me know if you have any doubts with the result.

Comment: Your most welcome @BibekPoudel. You can vote and mark this answer right, so that it would help more people who will come to your question in future

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access an element of a list by index just use square brackets `[` `]`:

```dart
final e = _subcoll[idx];
```

Dart will guess the type (at compile-time) here, for non-`final` variables you can use `var`.

In your case, an element is probably of type `Map<String, String>`, you can be explicit and specify it:

```dart
final Map<String, String> e = _subcoll[idx];
```

You can get the index of the first matching item with:

```dart
final int i = _subcoll.indexWhere((e)=>e["name"]=="java" && e["pdffile"]="pdf1");
```

The first matching item with:

```dart
final e = _subcoll.firstWhere((e)=>e["name"]=="java" && e["pdffile"]="pdf1");
```

Or an Iterable with all matching items with:

```dart
for(final e in _subcoll.where((e)=>e["name"]=="java" && e["pdffile"]="pdf1"){
    doSmth();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if I want to call it according to index then how can I access it according to index?

Comment: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-core/List/indexWhere.html

Comment: or are you just trying to get an item from the list by index? then its just `final e = _subcoll[idx]`